# Botón de buscar

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Quisiera que pongan un botón de buscar... Es que quiero usar solo el ratón y pegar lo que quiero buscar mediante click derecho y luego la opción pegar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi teclado está teniendo una serie de inconvenientes últimamente y además en ese momento no tenía ganas de usar el teclado, y mi sistema no tiene teclado en pantalla.

Solo tenía el ratón, y no pude buscar una pregunta porque no había un botón de buscar, de modo que la única manera era buscarla desde Google, que sí tiene ese botón... Pero me desanimé y ya no lo hice.

¿Qué les parece la idea?

Bueno... Con la idea que me dejó *lois6b* en los comentarios, ya terminé de programarle el *userscript*, lo dejo aquí al código por si quieren mirar... Se trata de un teclado en pantalla.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8" />
        <title>Teclado en pantalla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="search" />
        <script>
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Botón de buscar en SO
// @version    0.1
// @description  Para buscar con el ratón.
// @author     Eslacuare
// @match    *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var so_us = {}
window.so_us = so_us

so_us.escribir = function(){
  var e = this.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase()
  var n = so_us.entrada_seleccionada
  var u = 0, v = 0
  var estilo_teclado = so_us && so_us.teclado && so_us.teclado.style
  var arr = null, num = null, cambiar_atributo = null, sel = null
  var inicio = 0
  var fin = 0
  var buscar = document.querySelector("#search")
  estilo_teclado && (
    cambiar_atributo = (u,f,e,estilo,vector,relativo)=>{
      var r = new RegExp(`(^\\(${f}\\)$)`,"i").test(e)
      var valor = null
      r && (
        u = 7,
        arr = estilo_teclado[vector].match(/(\d|\.)+/),
        num = arr && + arr[0] || 0,
        valor = (num + relativo).toString(),
        vector=="opacity" && (
          valor = valor<0.1?0.1:valor>1?1:valor,
          so_us.opacidad = valor
        ) || (
          valor = valor.concat("px")
        ),
        estilo[vector] = valor
      )
      return u==6?u:u
    },
    u = cambiar_atributo(u,"←",e,estilo_teclado,"left",-10),
    u = cambiar_atributo(u,"→",e,estilo_teclado,"left", 10),
    u = cambiar_atributo(u,"↑",e,estilo_teclado,"top", -10),
    u = cambiar_atributo(u,"↓",e,estilo_teclado,"top" , 10),
    u = cambiar_atributo(u," \\+ ",e,estilo_teclado,"opacity", 0.1),
    u = cambiar_atributo(u," - ", e,estilo_teclado, "opacity",-0.1)
  )
  n && u<5 && (
    n.value==undefined && (n = n.target),
    buscar && /(^↵intro$)/i.test(e) && (
      u = 6,
      buscar.submit && buscar.submit() ||
      alert("Se ejecuta la búsqueda: " + n.value)
    ),
    e = e=="╙╌╌╜" ? "\x20" : e,
    e=="←" && (u = -1) && (v = 1),
    e=="↑" && (u = 2) && (v = 1),
    e=="↓" && (u = 3) && (v = 1),
    e=="→" && (u = 1) && (v = 1),
    so_us.inicio_seleccion = n.selectionStart,
    so_us.fin_selección = n.selectionEnd,
    so_us.inicio_seleccion != so_us.fin_selección && (v = 2),
    inicio = n.value.slice(0,so_us.inicio_seleccion),
    fin = n.value.slice(so_us.fin_selección),
    /(^[0-9a-zñ\[\]\x20áéíóú+-]$)/i.test(e) && (
      u = 4, v = 1,
      n.value = inicio + e + fin
    ),
    /(^↩$)/.test(e) && (
      (v != 2) && (inicio = inicio.slice(0,-1)),
      u = 4,
      v = v==2?v=0:v=-1,
      n.value = inicio + fin
    ),
    /(^supr)/i.test(e) && (
      (v != 2) && (fin = fin.slice(1)),
      u = 4, v = 0,
      n.value = inicio + fin
    ),
    ( u==-1 || u==1 ) && (
      v==2 && u==-1 && (v=0),
      v==2 && u== 1 && (
        v = so_us.fin_selección - so_us.inicio_seleccion
      ),
      v = v==1 ? u : v,
      n.selectionStart=so_us.inicio_seleccion + v,
      n.selectionEnd = so_us.inicio_seleccion + v
    )
  ),
  u==2 && (
    n.selectionStart = 0,
    n.selectionEnd = 0
  ),
  u==3 && (
    n.selectionStart = n.value.length,
    n.selectionEnd = n.value.length
  ),
  u==4 && (
    n.selectionStart = so_us.inicio_seleccion + v,
    n.selectionEnd = so_us.inicio_seleccion + v
  ),
  u<=5 && (
    so_us.entrada_seleccionada.focus==undefined && (
      sel = so_us.entrada_seleccionada.target
    )|| (
      sel = so_us.entrada_seleccionada
    ),
    sel.focus()
  )
}
so_us.seleccionar_entrada = function(x){
  so_us.entrada_seleccionada = x?x:this
}
so_us.es_entrada = function(x){
  return x && /(^input$)|(^textarea$)/i.test(x.tagName)
}
so_us.es_teclado = function(x){
  return x.classList.contains("teclado")
}
so_us.desaparecer = function(x){
  var b = 0
  if(x!=undefined){
    !so_us.es_entrada(x.target) && (b = so_us.opacidad)
    x==2 && (so_us.teclado.style.display = "none")
  }else{
    b = so_us.opacidad
  }
  b && so_us.teclado.style.opacity!==0 &&
    (so_us.teclado.style.opacity = 0)
}
so_us.aparecer = function(x){
  so_us.es_entrada(x.target) && (
    x.target.focus(),
    so_us.seleccionar_entrada(x.target)
  )
  so_us.es_entrada(document.activeElement) &&
    so_us.teclado.style.opacity!==so_us.opacidad &&
    (so_us.teclado.style.opacity = so_us.opacidad)
  if(so_us.teclado.style.display != "block"){
    so_us.teclado.style.display = "block"
  }
}
so_us.crear_teclado = function(){
  var t = document.createElement("table")
  var r = document.createElement("tr")
  var d = document.createElement("td")
  r.appendChild(d)
  t.appendChild(r)
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(t)
  so_us.teclado = t
  t.border = "1"
  t.style.display = "none"
  t.style.position = "fixed"
  t.style["z-index"] = 6000
  try{$ && (
    t.style.left = "230px",
    t.style.top = "140px"
  )}catch(e){
    t.style.left = "10px"
    t.style.top = "50px"
  }
  d.style["background-color"] = "#ff800040"
  d.addEventListener("mouseleave",so_us.desaparecer)
  d.addEventListener("mouseenter",so_us.aparecer)
  var regex = /(^[0-9a-zñ\[\]+-←↑↓→↩]$)|(^╙╌╌╜$)|(^supr$)|(^↵intro)/i
  var teclas = "1234567890 qweértyuúiíoóp aásdfghjklñ zxcvbnm"
    .split(" ").map(x=>{
      var i = document.createElement("div")
      var y = x.split("")
      y[0]=="1" && y.push(..."←↑↓→↩".split(""),"supr")
      y[0]=="q" && y.push("(↑)")
      y[0]=="a" && y.push("↵intro","(←)","(→)")
      y[0]=="z" && y.push(
        ..."[]+-".split(""),"( + )","( - )","(↓)","╙╌╌╜"
      )
      y.map(x=>{
        var o = document.createElement("button")
        var b = document.createElement("b")
        b.style.fontSize = "10px";
        var r = (regex.test(x)) && (
          o.style["background-color"] = "#80ff00a0"
        ) || (/[áéíóú]/i.test(x)) && (
          o.style["background-color"] = "#ff9010a0"
        ) || (o.style["background-color"] = "#20b0ffa0")
        o.classList.add("teclado")
        b.innerHTML = x.toUpperCase()
        o.addEventListener("click",so_us.escribir)
        o.appendChild(b)
        i.appendChild(o)
      })
      d.appendChild(i)
    })
  so_us.opacidad = 1
}

so_us.agregar_teclado_en_pantalla = function(){
  var entradas = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll("textarea,input")
  ].map(x=>{
    x.addEventListener("click",so_us.seleccionar_entrada)
    x.addEventListener("mouseleave",so_us.desaparecer)
    x.addEventListener("mouseenter",so_us.aparecer)
    x.autofocus = true
    !so_us.es_entrada(document.activeElement) &&
      !so_us.es_teclado(document.activeElement) &&
      so_us.desaparecer(2)
  })
}

so_us.crear_teclado()

setInterval(so_us.agregar_teclado_en_pantalla,100)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si no existe en SO en inglés, no lo van a poner en otros sitios primero. Podrías hacerte una extensión que añada un botón :P O puedes usar la URL con el parametro de busqueda: _"https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sfasdfad"_

Comment: @lois6b Gracias, buena idea, me haré un userscript.